# How to create a variable with multiple conditions in two different datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been working for developing a reference curve in a risky placenta thickness by week.
So I calculated quantiles of .03, .05, .10, .50, .90, .95, and .99 by each gestational week.

Consequently, I have two datasets for placenta thickness and quantiles. And I'd like to make a new variable, which presents outliers in the former dataset using the lowest and highest quantiles by week.

Here's examples of data:

```
Data A for thickness:
ID week day thickness
1  15   0   1.3
2  15   0   1.5
3  16   2   2.3
4  16   1   3.5
5  16   1   2.5
6  17   0   3.6
7  17   0   3.4
8  17   3   2.4

Data B for quantiles:
week .03  .05  .10  .50  .90  .95  .99
15   1.6  1.7  1.8  2.4  2.6  2.7  2.8
16   1.7  1.8  2.0  2.5  3.1  3.3  3.4
17   1.7  1.8  2.1  2.6  3.4  3.5  3.7
```

So I tried codes using `ifelse()` statement like below:

```
C<-within(A, {outlier = ifelse(A$Thickness<B[2] & A$week == B[1], 1, 0)
              outlier = ifelse(A$Thickness>B[8] & A$week == B[1], 1, 0)})
```

But an error occurred regarding the mismatched number of rows from each data.

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nl, value = list(outlier = c(0, 0,  :   replacement element 1 is a matrix/data frame of 33 rows, need 55808
```

The expected form of data based on Data A will be like this:

```
Data C:
ID week day thickness outlier
1  15   0   1.3       1
2  15   0   1.5       1
3  16   2   2.3       0
4  16   1   3.5       1
5  16   1   2.5       0
6  17   0   3.6       0
7  17   0   3.4       0
8  17   3   2.4       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base R solution I can think of.:

```
transform(A,outlier=as.numeric((C<-thickness-B[as.factor(week),c(2,8)])[,1]<0|C[,2]>0))

  ID week day thickness outlier
1  1   15   0       1.3       1
2  2   15   0       1.5       1
3  3   16   2       2.3       0
4  4   16   1       3.5       1
5  5   16   1       2.5       0
6  6   17   0       3.6       0
7  7   17   0       3.4       0
8  8   17   3       2.4       0
```

You can decide to write it as below:

```
C=A$thickness-B[as.factor(A$week),c(2,8)] #Only columns 2 and 8 subtract from A
transform(A,outlier=as.numeric(C[,1]<0|C[,2]>0)) #eg If the first column is -ve then an outlier

  ID week day thickness outlier
1  1   15   0       1.3       1
2  2   15   0       1.5       1
3  3   16   2       2.3       0
4  4   16   1       3.5       1
5  5   16   1       2.5       0
6  6   17   0       3.6       0
7  7   17   0       3.4       0
8  8   17   3       2.4       0
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). We can perform a join and then determine the outlier condition.

```
library(dplyr)

B2 <- B %>% select(week, X.03, X.99)

A2 <- A %>%
  left_join(B2, by = "week") %>%
  mutate(outlier = as.integer(thickness < X.03 | thickness > X.99)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("X"))
A2
#   ID week day thickness outlier
# 1  1   15   0       1.3       1
# 2  2   15   0       1.5       1
# 3  3   16   2       2.3       0
# 4  4   16   1       3.5       1
# 5  5   16   1       2.5       0
# 6  6   17   0       3.6       0
# 7  7   17   0       3.4       0
# 8  8   17   3       2.4       0
```

Here is the base R version of the same operation.

```
B2 <- B[, c("week", "X.03", "X.99")]
A2 <- merge(A, B2, by = "week", all.x = TRUE)
A2$outlier <- as.integer(A2$thickness < A2$X.03 | A2$thickness > A2$X.99)
A2[, c("X.03", "X.99")] <- NULL
A2
#   week ID day thickness outlier
# 1   15  1   0       1.3       1
# 2   15  2   0       1.5       1
# 3   16  3   2       2.3       0
# 4   16  4   1       3.5       1
# 5   16  5   1       2.5       0
# 6   17  6   0       3.6       0
# 7   17  7   0       3.4       0
# 8   17  8   3       2.4       0
```

Here is the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) version of the same operation.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(A)
setDT(B)

B2 <- B[, .(week, X.03, X.99)]

setkey(A, week)
setkey(B2, week)

A2 <- merge(A, B2)[, outlier := as.integer(between(thickness, X.03, X.99, incbounds = FALSE)), 
                   ][, c("X.03","X.99"):=NULL]
A2[]
#    week ID day thickness outlier
# 1:   15  1   0       1.3       1
# 2:   15  2   0       1.5       1
# 3:   16  3   2       2.3       0
# 4:   16  4   1       3.5       1
# 5:   16  5   1       2.5       0
# 6:   17  6   0       3.6       0
# 7:   17  7   0       3.4       0
# 8:   17  8   3       2.4       0
```

**DATA**

```
A <- read.table(text = "ID week day thickness
1  15   0   1.3
                2  15   0   1.5
                3  16   2   2.3
                4  16   1   3.5
                5  16   1   2.5
                6  17   0   3.6
                7  17   0   3.4
                8  17   3   2.4
                ",
                header = TRUE)

B <- read.table(text = "week .03  .05  .10  .50  .90  .95  .99
15   1.6  1.7  1.8  2.4  2.6  2.7  2.8
                16   1.7  1.8  2.0  2.5  3.1  3.3  3.4
                17   1.7  1.8  2.1  2.6  3.4  3.5  3.7",
                header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[B[c('week', '.03', '.99')], outlier := 
    as.integer(thickness < `.03`| thickness > `.99`), on = .(week)]
A
#   ID week day thickness outlier
#1:  1   15   0       1.3       1
#2:  2   15   0       1.5       1
#3:  3   16   2       2.3       0
#4:  4   16   1       3.5       1
#5:  5   16   1       2.5       0
#6:  6   17   0       3.6       0
#7:  7   17   0       3.4       0
#8:  8   17   3       2.4       0
```